# NSDate as function parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, nsdate, nstimezone

I'm facing an issue if I pass `NSDate` as a function parameter.

My code is:

```
self.PassDate(responseDate) ; // Response date value = 2015-05-15T00:00:00

func PassDate(date:NSDate) {

      // Here ideally date value should be same as responseDate value.. but date is coming as 2015-05-14T07:00:00 PDT
}
```

Why passing `NSDate` is changing the timezone/values?

Comment: `NSDate` does not have a time zone. I don't know where you're getting `PDF` in that function but it's not from the `NSDate`.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is changing. Different ways of viewing dates present them using different time zones. The underlying date is not changed. If you view the date in the debugger it (usually) shows it in UTC.

Try logging the date outside your function and inside using println() calls. You should see the same value in both places if you view it the same way each time.